# Wator/GameOfLife how to check for existing cell in console project?

Tags: c#

I wanted to try coding Wator/GameOfLife.
I have these two methods that fill the gameField and draw it.

```
        public void FillGameField()
        {
            Random X = new Random();
            Random Y = new Random();
            int totalCellNumber = Playground.GetLength(0) * Playground.GetLength(1);
            int totalPreyNumber = (int)(totalCellNumber * preyPercentage);
            int totalPredatorNumber = (int)(totalCellNumber * predatorPercentage);

            for (int i = 0; i < totalPreyNumber; i++)
            {
                int x = X.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(0));
                int y = Y.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(1));
                while (Playground[x, y] != null)
                {
                    x = X.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(0));
                    y = Y.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(1));                 
                }
                Playground[x, y] = new Prey();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < totalPredatorNumber; i++)
            {
                int x = X.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(0));
                int y = Y.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(1));
                while (Playground[x,y] != null)
                {
                    x = X.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(0));
                    y = Y.Next(0, Playground.GetLength(1));
                }

                Playground[x, y] = new Predator();
            }
        }

        public void DrawGameField()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Playground.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Playground.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    if(Playground[x,y] != null)
                    {
                        Console.Write(Playground[x, y].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

In the constructor i pass the size of the gamefield and also the percentage of prey and predator.
The FillGameField Method never ends. I also know why but i dont know how to fix this.
I just want to generate an X and Y Coordinate then check if the cell is empty if not regenerate till it is and the i generate a new Prey or Predator object but it takes way too long with percentages like 30 or 20. How can i optimize this?

Comment: Is `FillGameField` only called once?  I'm wondering if you have an infinite loop because everything is not null.  Any chance you could provide code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: it just takes very long because with low percentages it works

Comment: Then I would suggest a collection of non-null cells.  And just grab a random index inside of that.  Guarantees you get a non-null cell immediately.  Once you populate a cell, remove it from said collection of empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where preyPercentage and predatorPercentage are defined and set.  Please make sure that they're floating point numbers between 0 and 1.  Otherwise you'll have more predators and prey than you have cells.  The board will fill up, and you'll never stop looking for an empty cell to place the next one.

Picking a random point in the Playground until you find one that's not null isn't guaranteed to terminate, even if there are empty slots.  The random selection may just never find the right number.

If the size of the GameField is small enough then consider making a list of all the possible points, then shuffling that list into a random order, then picking the predator and prey locations from the list.

Comment: I generated all possible positions and picked a random one and it works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Start by grabbing all empty cells.

```
var emptyCells = Playground.SelectMany(x => x == null).ToList();
```

Then simply select (randomly) into that collection when populating cells, using that total for percentages at the start.

When you populate one of the items in `emptyCells` be sure to remove it from the collection.

You can also protect against a full board by checking `emptyCells.Count > 0`.

Comment: i appreciate your answer but i have to pick toastifer's answer but i tested yours too and it works. Still thank you! sry for my bad english btw.